# How to find where the props of a component come from

Tags: reactjs, react-props

Currently I'm unable to find where the props of a component are from. This component is

```
class sizeTable extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
 }
 this.state = {size:[...props.size]}
}

export default sizeTable
```

However, when I search this "sizeTable" in the whole project, I'm unable to find any place this "sizeTable" is used or imported in this whole project. I also tried react development tools in chrome, still can't find where this size props is passed from. May I know what could be the reason I can't find where it's imported and may I know what would be a good way to search? Thank you so much!

Comment: Is this your component?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Hi! It's not, I try to find where the sizeTable is imported and where the props is passed to this sizeTabl and search the whole project, but nothing was found. I don't know how should I do the search to get the where the sizeTable is used and passed the props

Comment: @Ying without more context it's *really* hard to help with this question, and I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but typically in today's React props are passed via JSX; in other words, are you searching your project for something like `<sizeTable size={someSize} />`?

Comment: @BrendanBond Hi! I think I may find it! if this component is "export default sizeTable", but another component is "import Table from ""../../sizetableroute" and pass params to this Table component, here even the name is changed from sizeTable to Table, it actually refers to this sizeTable component right? we can directly change the name when we do import without using "as"?